# Flask-sqlalchemy: Can I create multiple bind keys for the same db.model?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 2 empty databases. I have two tasks at hand.

TASK 1:

I want to create these two tables m1 & m2 in my primary database (sqlite) and add data to the tables.

TASK 2:

Then I want to copy those two tables(with data) from sqlite to my secondary database (mysql).

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
    'mysql': "mysql+pymysql://root@localhost/db",
}

db=SQLAlchemy(app)

class m1(db.Model):
    __tablename__= 'm1'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

class m2(db.Model):
    __tablename__= 'm2'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
```

Task1 is easy. I use `create_all()` to create tables and `db.session.add()` to add data to those tables.

Now, Task2 is the tricky one. I can't create tables in mysql because my session is bound to sqlite engine. I also can't switch sessions to query data from my primary database(sqlite) and add to my secondary database(mysql).

Possible ways to solve this issue (according to me).

1. Creating multiple binding keys for the same table/Model and switching engines whenever i want. For ex: I grab data from table m1 from sqlite, I switch to mysql engine and create table m1 and fill data (I don't know how).
2. Somehow creating multiple sessions ( you can't create, but if you have a way)
3. Anything else that you suggest.

Rules :

1. I'm talking about `flask_sqlalchemy` here (so don't write about plain `sqlalchemy`).
2. I don't want to use raw sql queries. Abstraction is important.
3. Before you jump in, to duplicate this question, understand the scenario of the question. If you find anything relevant, post them in the comments. If it helps me, you can go on duplicate it .

Comment: https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: flask-migrate is used to change database schema, but not for db to db transfer ( I guess). I cant find enough docs on this flask-migrate. Still I need answer to the question.

Comment: Why are you limited to a single session?

Comment: I can't create multiple sessions. There is only one `db.session()`. Based on the bindkey you provide, tables are created in the corresponding database. What I want to do is to be able to switch between multiple bindkeys. For ex: I have table m1. I want to create and fill data in m1 on sqlite, the i want to have the same table m1 to be created in mysql. For this I have to switch the bindkey from `None` to `mysql`.  I want to know how to change bindkey dynamically, so I can switch session from one db to another.

Comment: I think we can add a scoped session to join transactions. But the condition here is that I want to make changes on same table (m1) by switching between sqlite and mysql